# Cardinal characteristics -- generalisation?

Tags: reference-request, cardinals

I'm just reading about what is called cardinal characteristics of the continuum. For example there are the bounding number $\mathfrak b$ and the dominating number $\mathfrak d$ etc. which are defined to be certain cardinalities of sets of functions $\omega \to \omega$.

Where can I read about the corresponding combinatorics of sets of functions $\kappa \to \lambda$ for cardinals $\kappa, \lambda$ other than $\omega$? Or does it not make sense to ask this? Thanks.

Comment: *Almost* everything that I’ve seen deals with the case $\kappa=\lambda=\omega$, which is especially important, but there’s a little early work by Comfort in [this paper](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/106682).

Comment: Yes. It makes sense. I know that some people are interested in the cases of inaccessible cardinals, although I am not familiar enough with the topic to fully understand why. I know two students of Shelah that had worked on such topics, although I'm not sure whether or not there are reasonable publications to point at.

Comment: Ah, here is one example http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1947

Comment: Thanks to both of you! What would I do without you... : )

Comment: [This MO answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81850/cardinality-of-cofinal-set-of-normal-functions-f-colon-omega-1-to-omega-1/81865#81865) mentions the paper James Cummings and Saharon Shelah: *Cardinal invariants above the continuum*, Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 75 (1995), no. 3, 251–268.